# How do I get the bounding box of point data?

Tags: vtk

How do I get the range of the data set? Also known as the bounding box for the data. The data is read with the `StructuredPointsReader`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because vtkStructuredPoints (the type of GetOutput() on a vtkStructuredPointsReader) is a subclass of vtkDataSet, you can use the GetBounds(double[6]) function of vtkDataSet. Here is an example:

```
  double bounds[6];
  structuredPointsReader->Update();
  structuredPointsReader->GetOutput()->GetBounds(bounds);

  std::cout  << "xmin: " << bounds[0] << " " 
             << "xmax: " << bounds[1] << std::endl
             << "ymin: " << bounds[2] << " " 
             << "ymax: " << bounds[3] << std::endl
             << "zmin: " << bounds[4] << " " 
             << "zmax: " << bounds[5] << std::endl;
```