# 2D bounding box of a rendered 3D model using VTK

Tags: rendering, vtk, bounding-box

I am trying to find the 2D binding box of the rendered image of the 3D model using VTK. Is there anything which automatically find it for me? In the end I want to have something like this (but with the rendered image of an airplane 3D model instead of a real one):
http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2007/examples/aeroplane_03.jpg

If not I'll have to go, pixel by pixel, pick points and find the extreme points myself. Just wanted to know is there is something which automatically do it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what data type you have. For `vtkPolyData` you can just call `PolyDataObject.GetBounds()` and you will get the extreme points of your object in the format `-x, x, -y, y, -z, z`.

There is also a function [`vtkBoundingBox`](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkBoundingBox.html#details) that seems to do what you want.

In the end you should be able to solve this with something like `BoundingBox.SetBounds(Object.GetBounds())`.

Edit: As described [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484854/how-do-i-get-the-bounding-box-of-point-data), if you do not have a `vtkPolyData` object you can usually call `someObject.GetOutput().GetBounds()`.

Comment: I want to get bounding box of the model in the **rendered image** in pixels which are 2d coordinates. What you are referring to are the actual bounding box of a 3D model.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. In that case your problem is a little more complicated and I can't provide a nice solution. Do you want the bounding box in only one perspective/view or should it dynamically adjust when you rotate your view?

Comment: I want it for a particular view for the moment. Currently I'm going pixel by pixel and using pick points as described in the question. But it is really slow - takes like 1 - 2 minutes for bounding box for one view.

Comment: Did you try aligning the view to the out-of-plane coordinate axis so that you can use the two in-plane axes bounding box coordinates?

Comment: Hi, what is out-of-plane axis? I searched but couldn't get anything. Can you point me to some source? Thanks.

Comment: I'll elaborate: Assume your object is viewed in a way, that you want the bounds of the X and the Z coordinates (in-plane) and the Y axis points right at you (out-of-plane). In that case you can just basically ignore whatever the Y axis does, because you are only interested in X and Z. Then my original approach with `getBounds()` could apply again.

Comment: I am definitely transforming (rotating/translating) the object based on some parameters and then trying to get the bounding box in the rendered image.